# Return list based on calculations made from data in CSV files (WITHOUT CSV MODULE)

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

What I am trying to do is read a CSV file which has stats that are being used for a fantasy football team. The file looks like this:

```
Name    Team    G   QBRat   Comp    Att Pct Pass    Yds Pass    YG  Yds Att TD  Int
Matt    Flynn   GNB 5   124.8   33  49  67.3    518 103.6   10.6    6   2
Aaron   Rodgers GNB 15  122.5   343 502 68.3    4643    309.5   9.2 45  6
Tyrod   Taylor  BAL 3   118.8   1   1   100 18  6   18  0   0
Brian   Hoyer   NWE 3   118.8   1   1   100 22  7.3 22  0   0
Drew    Brees   NOR 16  110.6   468 657 71.2    5476    342.3   8.3 46  14
 ... etc.
```

I have limited time to do this, and I need it to be simple - meaning I can't use the `csv` module, and I can't use a bunch of advanced commands to execute it (I mean I could, but I don't want to use it if I cannot understand it).

What I have to do is:

1. **Read the stats from the files**. There are essentially 6 different CSV files, because I have to calculate and return lists for stats based on the quarterbacks, running backs, wide receivers, tight ends, kickers, and overall defense of teams. For now I will just stick to the quarterbacks as an example.
2. **Create a point system from this CSV file**. I have to go through each player's name and either add or subtract a certain amount of points based on their stats:

   - 4 pts per passing TD (TD - Rush TD)
   - 6 pts per rushing TD (Rush TD)
   - 1 pts for each 25 yards passing (Pass Yds)
   - 10 pts if completing rate over 60 percent (Pct)
   - 20 pts bonus if completion rate over 70 percent (Pct)
   - -2 for each sack (Sack)
   - -6 for each lost fumble (FumL)
3. **Return back (or print, whatever) the top 20**, in a list based on the number of points that is somewhat like this:

   ```
   Name________________________Team__________________Points
   ====________________________====__________________======
   player name_____________    their team______________how many points they have
   ```

I am lost and I really need some help, thanks to everyone who can provide some insight :)

This is where i'm at:

```
def qtrBacks():
    qb = open('NFL2011QB.csv', 'r')
    points = 0
    for Name in qb:


print('Top Quarterbacks')
print()
print('Name\t\t Team\t Points')
print('====\t\t ====\t ======')
```

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the `csv` module? Almost any solution is going to need to reinvent it (imperfectly) in order to get the data out of the CSV file, so it seems like a silly restriction. It's quite easy to use something like [`csv.DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest breaking the work into several functions. This can help you organize the work into separate pieces that can be tuned or modified separately.

First, I suggest handling the file parsing. This is important because it's where we determine the data structures that will hold the player data. I think keeping each player's stats in a dictionary makes sense, mapping from each stat name (like "TD") to the value. Here's a function that uses a list comprehension to build a list of such dictionaries, one for each player, taking the stat names from the file's header. If the file doesn't have correct headers for each column this may not work right.

```
def read_player_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        head = f.readline().split("\t")

        player_list = [dict(zip(head, line..strip().split("\t"))) for line in f]

    return player_list
```

The code above is pretty much equivalent to what you could do with the `csv` module, though it probably won't handle slightly messed up files as well. Here's an alternative version using `csv.DictReader`:

```
def read_player_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        return player_list = list(csv.DictReader(f))
```

Both of those implementations are (hopefully) independent of the specifics of the file, so you can use them for each of your CSV files, even if they have different stats.

The next thing to code up is the scoring function. I'm not entirely sure how to do this for the rules you listed, since there's only one `TD` column in your example data (with no separate running TD value) and no columns for sacks or fumbles.

```
def qb_score(player_dict):             # FIXME: Replace ? values!
    run_td = ?
    pass_td = int(player_dict["TD"]) - run_td
    pass_yards = int(player_dict["Yds Pass"])
    sacks = ?
    fumbles = ?
    completion_rate = float(player_dict["Pct Pass"])

    score = 4*pass_td + 6*run_td + pass_yards//25 - sacks*2 - fumbles*4

    if completion_rate > 60:
        score += 10
    if completion_rate > 70: # maybe this should be an elif?
        score += 20

    return score
```

Now, we can put them the parts together and return the best-scoring QBs:

```
def top_qbs(count=20):
    qb_list = read_player_file("NFL2011QB.csv")

    for qb in qb_list:
        qb["qb score"] = qb_score(qb)

    qb_list.sort(key=lambda qb:qb["qb score"], reversed=True)

    return qb_list[:count]
```

You could make your printout with something like:

```
def print_top_qbs():
    qbs = top_qbs()

    print('Top Quarterbacks')
    print()
    print('Name\t\t Team\t Points')
    print('====\t\t ====\t ======')
    for qb in qbs:
        print("{Name}\t{Team}\t{qb score}".format(**qb))
```